# Check if computer is connected to the internet

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, internet

Write a program which, according to whether the script has access to the internet, produces an output which is ["Truthy/Falsey"](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey). You may try and connect to any existing site, **at your own discretion** (don't use a shady site which only has 10% uptime - try to keep to above 80% annual uptime). If the site is down, your program does *not* have to work.

It must be a **standalone program** or a **function**. You may use libraries outside of the standard library to achieve this. [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden. This is code golf, so the code with the shortest byte-count wins.

Example pseudocode:

```
function a:
    try:
        connect to internet 
        return 1
    catch error:
        return 0
```

This is my first post on code golf, so if this violates any rules in any way or is a dupe, please alert me.

EDIT: Due to numerous suggestions, I have removed the UTF-8 byte count restriction

Comment: Instead of `true` and `false`, I recommend allowing any of our [defaults for truthy and falsiness](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2190/32686). Also, by internet, do you mean the network outside your local network? Do programs still have to work if say google is down or any other large site?

Comment: @muddyfish thanks so much for your answer! I will edit my question to be more clear :)

Comment: Byte count is usually done in the language's native or most convenient encoding, which is not always UTF-8. Unless you a have a good reason to enforce UTF-8, I think the encoding should be left at the programmer's choice

Comment: @LuisMendo I chose this to prevent ambiguity

Comment: I see almost everyone is using [`g.gl` / `http://g.gl/`](http://g.gl/), but [`to.` / `http://to./`](http://to./) seems to be one byte shorter (not all languages see it as a valid url through).

Comment: Commodore Basic: `PRINT "0"`

Comment: The very machine I'm typing this at, is technically a part of the "Internet",
as it can be accessed from the outside (via NAT and port forwarding).

So, if you think of it, the "internet detection" script can probably be reduced to "true" :)

Comment: @Restioson We have a Meta question to define how to count size of programs. Enforcing counting in UTF8 is just going to make things more confusing. Also, what if someone solves this in, say, Vim? Or TI-Basic? How do you count those in UTF8?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen [`to`](http://to) (without the `.` at the end) also seems to work.

Comment: What is an objective definition of "80% uptime"? And is that defined to be in the last week, last month, or what?

Comment: Another thing, does the code have to check/ping live internet sites or is checking the DNS server okay? Because the DNS server being operational doesn't *technically* mean your computer can connect to the WWW, even if it might usually do.

Comment: @H Walters The reason I said "WWW" is because that's how I interpreted the question. If OP meant just the internet, that would be different.

Comment: @TheBitByte true. But I mean do not use a site which is only on on Thursdays, for example. Keep it sensible

Comment: @zeppelin your computer would no longer be connected to the internet, if, say, I made your means of network communication break, e.g unplugging your ethernet cable

Comment: @TheBitByte yes, checking a DNS server is OK, as long as it *isn't* on your local network (LAN, hosted by your local router)

Comment: It's nice that my question has mainly "mainstream" languages in answers as opposed to the usual horde of esolangs in answers.

Comment: @Restioson This is Code Golf SE. I'm not sure what answers you were expecting to get. Anyways, can I just ping the DNS server without having to ping a live WWW website? In other words, *technically* the ISP's DNS server working isn't always an indication of the WWW working, even if it usually is.

Comment: @Mark `? 0` (or even `?0`?) should do it.  Untested - from memory.

Comment: @NobodyNada Hmm.. It doesn't for me, and I tested it on three different devices/networks. :S

Comment: @Mark - not really. There *is* a TCP/IP implementation for Commodore 64, and there even are network cards for C64 with embedded TCP/IP.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen seems http://to. is down now

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Bash (with *dnsutils*), 3 bytes

Sends a DNS request for "." (DNS root), exit code is 0 for success and >0 otherwise.

**Golfed**

```
dig
```

**Test**

```
% dig >/dev/null; echo $?;        
0

% nmcli nm wifi off
% dig >/dev/null; echo $?;
9
```

**Disclaimer**

This will obviously only work if your *DNS* server is sitting in the provider's network, i.e. in the "Internet" (as your provider network is normally a part of it), or if your system is using a public DNS server (like 8.8.8.8 from Google, which Android based systems use), as otherwise, you can get a cached copy from a local *LAN* server (or localhost).

But I assume this is not against the [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules, as there are obviously more than one system where this does work as intended.

Pure-HTTP methods can also give false positives, due to an intermediate caching proxy, and are not guaranteed to work everywhere, so that is not something unique to this method.

**A slightly more reliable version, 8 bytes**

```
dig +tra
```

(a little tribute to @**Dig**ital **Tra**uma !)

Enables the "trace mode", which will force *dig* to do the recursive search by itself (see https://serverfault.com/a/778830), avoiding any cache issues.

Comment: Quote from `man dig`: Unless it is told to query a specific name server, dig will try each of the servers listed in _/etc/resolv.conf_. If no usable server addresses are found, dig will send the query to the **local host**.

Comment: @Titus, yep that is correct, see "disclaimer" part of my answer, but as long as your DNS server (as specified in your resolv.conf) is on your provider's side, it works just nice.

Comment: Your solution depends on a non-default install; I woukld consider that exploiting a loophole. You can still win with the two additional bytes.

Comment: >Your solution depends on a non-default install
Nope, it is exactly how it works on my machine (and that is already enough according to Meta). Moreover, using your provider's DNS server,  is a pretty common setup indeed (and it will normally be in your resolv.conf too).

Comment: @Titus there are also lots of systems around which will just use public DNS servers (like 8.8.8.8 from Google), e.g. almost every Android-based system.

Comment: defualt settigns depends on what settings you used at install time if you configured the network using DHCP then resolv.conf probably points at your router. if you configured networking manually it will have whatever DNS server you nominated.

Comment: What if you're connected to a LAN with DNS, but not the internet?  People who are trying to lookup short web sites _on_ the internet here are going to figure out if they are on the internet versus such LAN's... this solution doesn't seem to be even trying to do that.

Comment: @HWalters

>What if you're connected to a LAN with DNS, but not the internet?
Then you will (possibly) get a cached response (as described in "Disclaimer").
 
>... figure out if they are on the internet versus such LAN'
Only if they do not have a caching proxy, like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), in their LAN (which is a _very common_ setup too), in which case they will just get a cached response every time.
 
The point is that there is still a (considerable) number of real-world setups, that will work just nice, e.g. most Android devices will just use a public Google DNS.

Comment: @zeppelin I'm not sure we're on the same wavelength.  You're talking about cached entries here (and in your disclaimer).  And sure, if the LAN's connected and then disconnected, such creatures might indeed exist.  But that's kind of way off to the side of what I'm talking about... _live_ DNS entries on the LAN... entries about the LAN, not generally accessible from the internet.  (Maybe WAN gives you a better image).

Comment: > live DNS entries on the LAN... entries about the LAN, not generally >accessible from the internet (Maybe WAN gives you a better image).

HTTP-based method might as well fail to detect an isolated WLAN (e.g. if there is a proxy server which will return a "dummy" page, explaining that internet access is disabled in response to any "external" URI).
(which is pretty normal for a corporate WLAN).

But that is not the point, really, as long as there are at least some real-world setups, the method works for, that is just fine for the purposes of [codegolf].

Comment: Great answer! Wouldn't have thought an answer so short possible! Well done.

Answer (score 19):

## Bash + GNU utils, 8

- 5 bytes saved thanks to @Muzer.

```bash
wget to.
```

The other shell answers check the return code and echo some status output accordingly.  This is unnecessary.  The shell return code is already a usable Truthy/Falsey code and accessible in the `$?` parameter which is idiomatic for bash.  Return code 0 means True.  Return code >0 means False.

In use:

```bash
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ wget to.
--2017-01-13 09:10:51--  http://to./
Resolving to. (to.)... 216.74.32.107, 216.74.32.107
Connecting to to. (to.)|216.74.32.107|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 11510 (11K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.6’

index.html.6        100%[===================>]  11.24K  --.-KB/s    in 0.04s   

2017-01-13 09:10:51 (285 KB/s) - ‘index.html.6’ saved [11510/11510]

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo $?
0
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ifconfig ens33 down
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ wget to.
--2017-01-13 09:11:00--  http://to./
Resolving to. (to.)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘to.’
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo $?
4
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ifconfig ens33 up
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ # Local network up, upstream link down
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ wget to.
--2017-01-13 09:11:34--  http://to./
Resolving to. (to.)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘to.’
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo $?
4
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Use a domain like `to.` rather than `8.8.8.8`, to save quite a lot.

Comment: @Muzer yes - thanks

Comment: Needs to have the dot at the end I'm afraid, otherwise it searches on your local network.

Comment: @Muzer unless there is a local `to` that the resolver is configured to find, it will still go to the right one (and maybe being able to ping a local `to` is enough of _being connected to the internet_)

Comment: @Muzer OK, `to` sometimes works and sometimes not.  I guess some caching going on.  I'll use `to.` just for safety.

Comment: Why is that a valid domain?

Comment: This doesn't work for me: https://hastebin.com/uviceyomiw.pas, maybe it's a Ubuntu thing?

Comment: @Kos because there's no reason it wouldn't be valid?

Answer (score 9):

### Batch, 8 bytes

```
ping to.
```

`ping` will set `ERRORLEVEL` to `1` if the address cannot be resolved or reached.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

Saved 2 bytes on "to." courtesy of *ev3commander*

```
…to..wgX›
```

Checks if the length of the content at http://to. is greater than 1.
`.w` returns 0 on error.

Comment: Always a +1 for 05AB1E answers

Comment: @WorseDoughnut And why is that?

Comment: @mbomb007 Just been a huge fan of the language since Adnan starting working on it and posting it here; it's definitely a fascinating language to delve into.

Comment: @WorseDoughnut There's already a hyperlink in the answer.

Comment: Can't you connect to http://to./ to save a byte?

Comment: @ev3commander: Apparently I can. Didn't work when i tried yesterday but it does now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

### R, 20 bytes

```
curl::has_internet()
```

There's a function for exactly this task in the `curl` package.

Comment: +1 nice find. For those curious like me, this function is implemented as: `function() !is.null(nslookup("r-project.org", error = FALSE))`

Comment: Equivalent count: `httr::url_ok('g.gl')` (albeit deprecated).

Comment: @JonathanCarroll if you used 'to.' in that it would be one byte less :)

Answer (score 6):

### Bash <s>66</s> <s>62</s> 21 bytes

```
ping -c1 g.gl echo $?
```

Thanks @Alex L. for the URL shortening tip.

Ungolfed version:

```
r=$(ping -c1 g.gl)
if [ $? -ne 0 ];
 then echo "0"
else echo "1"
fi
```

This is my first answer in Bash , i'm not sure i have shortened the script enough.

Comment: I think you can use a shorter URL than google.com, which would allow you to shorten the code. Something like g.gl.

Comment: You should also be able to just `echo $?` instead of that whole if statement.

Comment: you missed "some" `;` in the golfed line.

Comment: @IporSircer Thanks. :)
@SomethingDark Hello, `echo $?`  prints a `0` if success, or else it returns a `2` in this case. I have not looked into source code of the implementation of `ping` but i am assuming, there are different return codes depending on the stuation. Hence, i used `if else` strategy.

Comment: @AbelTom - it could be argued that 0 is truthy and non-0 is falsey.

Comment: @SomethingDark Haha, i tried to negate the return value too, but I could not and don't know how. `0` is accepted as truthy? i mean would that be compliant with the spec ?

Comment: Yeah, bash traditionally considers [0 to be success and everything else to be a failure](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you're setting a variable at all; you can just say `ping -c1 g.gl;echo $?` (or `to.` instead of `g.gl` like some other people are doing)

Comment: @SomethingDark I actually wanted to do that initially, but i thought output should be only either `0` or `1`. There's some unwanted text too when i run this program, thats the reason i stored it in a variable.

Comment: 14 bytes, using `-a` (audible bell) for Truthy: `ping -ac1 g.gl`

Answer (score 6):

## Java, 72 bytes

```
a->new java.net.InetSocketAddress("to.",80).getAddress().isReachable(9);
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

*One byte saved thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)'s suggestion*

```
'http://to.'Xi
```

Output is through STDOUT. This displays a non-empty string containing non-zero chars (which is truthy) if there is an Internet connection; and displays nothing (which is falsy) if there's no connection.

This can't be tested online because the `Xi` is not allowed in the online interpreters.

#### Explanation

```
'http://to.'  % Push this string
Xi            % Return contents of that URL as a string. If there is no Internet
              % connection this gives an error, with no output on STDOUT
```

Comment: Would you consider `urlread('http://g.gl')` to be an OK answer by itself? It will error and leave the workspace empty if the connection is down. It will display an error message, but technically that's to STDERR...? I thought it was a bit of a stretch, so I did it [this way](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106714/31516). But skipping `try` seems to give the same result as your code, or? You leave the stack empty too don't you? Nice answer by the way... :)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks! Yes, I think `urlread('http://g.gl')` is valid (and is the same as my code does), as STDERR is ignored by default, and an empty STDOUT is falsy in MATLAB

Comment: would this work with `ftp` instead of `http` - save another byte?

Comment: @Floris Nice to see you also here! Unfortunately `ftp` doesn's seem to work for that site

Comment: Hello @LuisMendo yes I sometimes prowl other sites... too bad the ftp doesn't work!

Answer (score 4):

### C#, 87 bytes

```
_=>{try{new System.Net.WebClient().OpenRead("http://g.gl");return 1;}catch{return 0;}};
```

If an exception is considered falsey, which I don't think it is, then this is 65 bytes:

```
_=>new System.Net.WebClient().OpenRead("http://g.gl").ReadByte();
```

I also tried using the link `http://to.` as stated by @KevinCruijssen but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), <s>23</s> 21 bytes

*Two bytes saved thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) suggestion* and to my discovery: http://to seems to work as well as http://to. (saving another byte)

```
"http://to" net:get .
```

If site http://to can be reached, it then prints `true`. Otherwise it prints `false`.
It leaves retrieved data on the stack.

Comment: TOS means *t*op *o*f *s*tack. i think you mean it just leaves data on the stack.

Comment: That's right. I improved my explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @ev3commander Have you tried with [http://to](http://to) ? It works in my case (I see an Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page). It seems that there is no need to append '.' or '/'

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 15 bytes

```pl
print`curl to.`
```

Run with:

```
perl -e 'print`curl to.`' 2> /dev/null
```

`curl` outputs stuffs on `STDERR`, don't mind them. If the computer has access to internet, it will print a few lines of html (truthy), otherwise, it will print nothing (falsy).

*Saved 1 bytes by using `to.` (instead of my previous `b.io`) thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen.*

Comment: Couldn't you switch to bash and remove the `print`?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Yup, that would work (there is already a answer in bash though (they use `wget` instead of `curl` but it's the same thing)).

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, 16 bytes

```js
navigator.onLine
```

Returns `true` or `false`.

[Try It!](https://jsconsole.com/?navigator.onLine)

<sub>I'm new here, so IDK if I counted bytes properly, or if builtins are cheating...</sub>

Comment: Hi! Welcome to CGCC! I suggest adding a place where we can try this online (usually, we link [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#), but feel free to link anywhere else).

Comment: Bytes have been counted correctly. Also, builtins are not cheating unless the challenge disallowed it (which it does not).

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB, <s>32</s> 22 bytes

```
urlread('http://g.gl')
```

**Explanation:**

If the internet connection is up, this will result in `ans` (the default variable) being a string with the entire html-code in plain text (which is **true** in MATLAB).

If the internet connection is down, this will write an error message to STDERR and leave the workspace empty (which is **false** in MATLAB).

Unfortunately, [`urlread`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html) requires a *full url-address*, so `g.gl` is not enough. 11 of the 22 bytes are therefore just the url-address.

---

**Alternative approach:**

A solution that catches the error and leave a 0 (also **false**) in the workspace if the connection is down:

```
0;try urlread('http://g.gl'),end
```

`0;` initializes the default variable `ans` to `0`, which is `false` in MATLAB. Then we [`try`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/use-trycatch-to-handle-errors.html) to read the url. This will give an error if the internet connection is down, or a character array if not (which is `true` in MATLAB).

We don't need to catch anything, so we just end. If the urlread call was successful, then `ans` will be a long string with the content of the website, otherwise `ans=0`.

Answer (score 3):

### Bash, 39 bytes

```
exec 4<>/dev/tcp/to./80&&echo 1||echo 0
```

Comment: `! exec 4<>/dev/tcp/to./80;echo $?`

Comment: or if you don't need to print true/false but can just return it,`exec 4<>/dev/tcp/to./80`

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, <strike>71</strike> 43 bytes

```
fetch``.then(a=>alert(1)).catch(a=>alert``)
```

Alerts 1 if online, alerts an empty string if offline. Thanks to Patrick Roberts for helping me shave off some bytes

Old version

```
_=>fetch('http://enable-cors.org').then(a=>alert(a)).catch(a=>alert(0))
```

Alerts `[object Reponse]` if online, alerts `0` if offline

Removed the code snippet, it doesn't work because it loads from a different domain without CORS, but it works in the browser console

Comment: Hmm. This correctly prints "true" when I'm connected, but it doesn't print anything if I disconnect and run it in my browser. What browser/OS did you test this in? I'm using chrome-win7

Comment: @DJMcMayhem How's your cache?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I tested in Chrome, Win10. Disabled cache from the network tab and checked Offline to test offline/online

Comment: This can be a full program in 52 bytes: `fetch('://to.').then(a=>alert(1)).catch(a=>alert(0))`

Comment: Doesn't `navigator.onLine` work?

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica 10 Bytes

Assuming you have a valid copy of Mathematica, and login credentials on user.wolfram.com

```
CloudPut@1
```

will write the value 1 to the cloud.
Truthy: CloudObject[""] 
Falsey: $Failed

```
CloudGet@%
```

Will return the value 1 that was uploaded to the cloud.

Comment: Note that, by default, REPL snippets are not allowed. Put `&` afterwards to make it into an unnamed function.

Comment: Can you point me to a link?

Comment: See [Default for Code Golf: Program, Function or Snippet?](http://meta.ppcg.lol/q/2419).

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best answer here. But does Cloud object count as truthy? I would say that the 1 in the cloud is truthy, though. Nice answer!

Comment: @LegionMammal978, I can put the code, as is, in a .wl package file and run it as a "program" as allowable per the original question.  Ordinarily these sorts of questions call for a function with inputs; no user input is necessary.  Furthermore, testing of my truthy/false as a function works just as well with or without the &.  In `CloudPut@1&===$Failed` the & makes absolutely no difference. Lastly, the program both returns and prints the output, so it is not in fact a REPL snippet as you suggest.

Comment: @KellyLowder Look up Mathematica scripts. In full programs, only values outputted with `Print` are actually put on STDOUT.

Answer (score 2):

## <strike>PHP, 23</strike> PHP + Curl, 14

Using PHP's backtick operator:

```
<?=`curl to.`;
```

---

*Orignal answer:*

I will try to make a start:

```
<?=file('http://x.gl');
```

This outputs nothing if x.gl can't be reached and `Array` if it is.

Another version where I'm not quite sure if they fit:

```
<?=getmxrr('x.gl',$a);  // 22 chars
```

Comment: Re "is that a loophole", I think the normal consensus is that it counts as a language dialect (so the answer is **PHP + Curl, 15 bytes**).

Comment: Does an array count as truthy? I'll allow it to compete anyway though, since it is my question. Just out of interest.

Comment: @Restioson php converts an array to the string `"Array"` when you try to print it (`<?=`) and boolean false will be converted to `""`. So the actual return value is not an array but a non empty string or an empty string.

Comment: @Cristoph I don't think "Array" counts  as truthy or falsey

Comment: @Restioson It's a string that implicitly converts to boolean true. A branch `if ("Array") echo 'thruthy';` would be taken therefore it's [truthy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/29637). The empty string wouldn't take the branch and is therefore falsey.

Comment: @Cristoph ah OK. Most langs I've  seen do not do this afaik

Answer (score 2):

### Powershell, <s>64</s> <s>26</s> 23 bytes

Saved 38 bytes, thanks to Shawn Esterman

Saved 3 bytes, and repaired script, thanks to briantist

```
Test-Connection -q g.gl
```

Comment: Test-Connection -Quiet to.

Comment: PowerShell can't resolve `to.`, you'd have to use `g.gl` instead. Additionally you can shorten it to `Test-Connection -q g.gl`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, <strike>90</strike> 81 Bytes

```
f=a=>{i=new Image();i.src="//placehold.it/1x1";i.onload=b=>a(1);i.onerror=c=>a()}
```

## JavaScript ES6, <strike>22</strike> 21 bytes (Invalid)

Some browsers don't fully support, or produce the expected result when using navigator.onLine.

```
f=a=>navigator.onLine
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14283180/3398583) implies that this won't always return false when not connected to the internet

Comment: You can save a byte by adding a parameter to the lambda, like so: `f=a=>`

Comment: Although your answer still seems to be invalid, you can get rid of `f=`.

Comment: 78 bytes: `a=>{with(new Image()){src="//placehold.it/1x1";onload=b=>a(1);onerror=c=>a()}}´ (got rid of `f=` and used `with(){}`)

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 54 bytes

```
x=>(Runtime.getRuntime exec "ping -c 1 ai."waitFor)<1
```

Pretty simple; executes a ping command to `http://ai./`, and returns true if it exits with 0, or false otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 + requests, <s>59</s> <s>55</s> <s>53</s> 39 bytes

There has to be a requests answer, right?

```
from requests import*
get("http://to.")
```

Exit status is 0 for internet, 1 for no internet. Example:

```
$ python inet.py 
$ echo $?
0
$ # Remove ethernet cable
$ python inet.py 
$ echo $?
1
```

Changelog:

- -4 bytes (thanks Mego)
- -14 bytes (thanks pppery)

Comment: You could shorten this by using a different protocol (`ftp`, perhaps), and doing `except:0/0`.

Comment: @Mego I think requests only does http(s). I've added the 0/0.

Comment: Why is the try-except statement necessary?

Comment: @pppery Umm, yes. Thanks for pointing it out. I have no idea. Must have been a relic of the original solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
`g.gl`¨U
```

*Wait, `¨U` exists?*

Doesn't work on the online interpreter. Exits with error for falsy, runs successfully with no output for truthy.

```
`g.gl`   # string literal g.gl
      ¨U # GET request to that URL
```

For fun, here's a fairly cheaty version. Ports JavaScript:

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `E`, 13 bytes

```
`ƈ⌈(₍†.on¬ḣ)`
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJFIiwiIiwiYMaI4oyIKOKCjeKAoC5vbsKs4bijKWAiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Just runs the JavaScript `alert(navigator.onLine)` using the `E` flag

Comment: I thought it was `¨G`

Comment: You can use the url `\`to.\`` for one byte less.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.7, 70 <s>77</s> Bytes

```
from urllib import*
a=1
try:urlopen('http://to.')
except:a=0
print a
```

```
import urllib as l
try: 
 l.urlopen('http://a.uk')
 print 1
except:
 print 0
```

Uses 1 for truthy, 0 for falsy.  a.uk redirects to a motorbike clothing company.  Saved 3 bytes by assigning to a variable and printing that. And another one for the "to." trick (confirmed to work with urllib), two for getting rid of the pesky indents.

Comment: I think `from urllib import*` could save a char (and drop `l.` of course).

Comment: @NickT I forgot you could drop the space between `import` and `*` so I think you're right but I'm on mobile and I'll fix it later

Answer (score 1):

## Elixir, 33 bytes

```
{:ok,_}=:inet.getaddr('to',:inet)
```

0 if connected, 1 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia + Bash (with dnsutils), 10 bytes

```
run(`dig`)
```

`` `command` `` in julia creates a `cmd` object that can be run with `run`.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 12 bytes

```powershell
!!(irm g.gl)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io/), 21 bytes

```
download"http://x.gl"
```

Outputs via exit code.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 18 bytes

(2 bytes shorter than the [previous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106845/86301) R answer; additionally, this solution does not require an external package to be installed.)

```r
!is.null(nsl("a"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/XzGzWC@vNCdHI684R0MpUUlT8/9/AA)

The `nsl` function looks up the IP address of a hostname. If there is no Internet connection, it outputs `NULL`, otherwise it outputs an IP address.

Note that we do not need to specify an existing domain name: when the domain name does not resolve (and as long as it does not end in a `.`), the domain name is instead appended to the server domain name. So we can use any 1-letter domain name, and the output of `nsl` is the non-NULL server IP. I think this behaviour is not specific to R.

Answer (score 1):

## Scratch (scratchblocks3 syntax), 32 bytes

```
define
say(translate(1)to(Zulu v
```

"1" on success and an empty string on failure. Relies on Google Translate.

(Also, a slightly more amusing solution that actually outputs "true" but was unfortunately not optimal:)

```
define
say(translate(gwir)to(English v
```

Comment: Wouldn't translating to Lao be shorter, or does Scratch not support it?

Comment: @Restioson Scratch doesn't support Lao, for some reason. The shortest language names are Thai and Zulu

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 49 bytes

```clj
#(try(slurp"http://to.")1(catch Exception _ nil))
```

Returns `1` if it can connect, and `nil` otherwise.

Just attempts to `slurp` the page; throwing a `NoRouteToHostException` exception on failure, which is caught.

Unfortunately, the protocol and dot seem to be mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (Nashorn), 61 bytes

```
print(new java.net.InetSocketAddress("to.",80).getAddress())
```

Based on Huntro's Java answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 90 bytes

```lua
_,c=require('socket.http').request('http://g.gl')if string.find(c,'not')then os.exit(1)end
```

Sends a request to `g.gl` - exits with code `1` if can't connect